# React js componentWillUnmount for callbacks

Tags: reactjs

I have read [isMounted is an Antipattern](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/16/ismounted-antipattern.html) and am still unsure if the codes below will cause memory leak when using with callback?

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.mounted = true
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.mounted = false
  }
  someAPIcall() {
    callSomething(argument, (err, result) => {
      if (this.mounted === false) return
      // otherwise do something
      this.setState({...})         
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: That looks okay for me. You'd be better off using this.state for your mounted property as well :)

Answer (score 1):

It's better to do that :

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    someAPIcall();
  }

  someAPIcall() {
    callSomething(argument, (err, result) => {

      this.setState({...})         
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is right. This will guarantee the API call only goes through once it's mounted. Let React figure out when the component mounted, no need to do it yourself.